# Why does the many-worlds theory assume that the wave function is all there is?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, quantum-interpretations

[Many-worlds interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-worlds_interpretation) says that the wave functions is all there is. And that the entire universe has only one wave function.

But quantum mechanics does not fully reconcile with gravity and there is a possibility that it may have to be tweaked and the wave function would not be all there is?

So what is the justification for holding this assumption (wave function is everything) in absence of a theory of quantum gravity?

Comment: Perhaps because it's expected that someday there *will* be a satisfactory theory of quantum gravity.  Keep in mind that in science, all assumptions are subject to revision when new, contradictory evidence requires it.

Comment: Given that we do have candidate theories of quantum gravity namely -  String Theory and Loop Quantum Gravity, do they in their current formulation validate this assumption? Or do they say absolutely nothing about it?

Comment: We don't have candidate theories of quantum gravity. We have some vague sketches of candidate theories of quantum gravity, all of which are direly incomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proposition "The wavefunction is all there is" is meant to clarify the difference between the many-worlds theory of quantum mechanics and some other quantum mechanical interpretations. In many other interpretations there are additional physical laws required to explain what happens during a measurement. In those interpretations there is, in addition to the dynamical evolution of the wavefunction, a special process which happens during a measurement which does not follow the regular evolution of the wavefunction, but leads to instantaneous collapse of the wave function. The quote is meant to indicate that in the many-worlds interpretation no such extra laws are required to explain observations. The wavefunction is all there is.

Note that the many worlds interpretation is not unique in this and there are other explanations, that are also able to explain what is observed during a measurement, whithout introducing new instantaneous processes.

This whole discussion stands completely separate from the problem of integrating quantum mechanics and gravity. While some people might think a theory of quantum gravity will be based on a wavefunction for both particles and spacetime, this is not known and not part of the many worlds interpretation of quantum mechanics.

Comment: Decoherence categorically cannot explain measurements, decoherence only explains how density matrices can become classical, in the sense that all interference terms average out. No amount of decoherence will produce individual eigenvalue observations, it will only give you a classical statistics limit

Comment: @Crimson Can you explain why is the assumption of wave function, completely separate from integrating quantum mechanics and gravity? Since, if we find out that the wave function is not the complete picture and needs to be modified to include gravity, then can we still consider many worlds as an explanation? And if quantum gravity does not involve the wavefunction then it must introduce some other explanation and then the wavefunction will not be the complete picture. 
And also I am sure that I am completely missing some simple bit of reasoning here and hence asking this!

Comment: @YashSharma  You are right. The wave function is not completely separate from integrating quantum mechanics and gravity. It probably will play a large roll in it. However, the quote from your question is typically not intended to include gravity, but only meant to clarify the difference with other QM interprestations. Only if a theory for quantum gravity is found, we will figure out whether the wavefunction truly is al there is.